# Redirect Api duplicate NextJS use SWR

Tags: typescript, next.js

I use SWR to fetch data but get the error of repeating the default path of nextjs
`http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/get-five-post-popular?skip=0&limit=5`

tsx:

```
'use client'
import useSWR from "swr";
import HomeOutstanding from "@/components/partials/home/HomeOutstanding ";

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

const  API_POST_POPULAR = process.env.API_URL + ':' + process.env.API_PORT + '/api/posts/get-five-post-popular?skip=0&limit=5'

export default function Home() {

  const { data, error, isLoading} = useSWR(
    API_POST_POPULAR,
    fetcher
  )
  if  (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div>Failed to api</div>
  }
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }
```

.env:

```
API_URL=127.0.0.1
API_PORT=8000
```

How to get the correct path http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/get-five-post-popular?skip=0&limit=5 . Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the "http://" in front of the url.
Without it fetch think's the request should come to localhost

Try something like.

```js
const url = `http://${process.env.API_URL}:${process.env.API_PORT}/api/posts/get-five-post-popular?skip=0&limit=5`
```

or just include it in the env variable

```
API_URL='http://127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Thank you change to API_URL= http://127.0.0.1 fix to issuse

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended not to construct URLs by hand via string concatenation.
Instead you can use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) api:

```js
// const baseUrl = new URL(process.env.API_URL + ':' + process.env.API_PORT);

// after variable substitution:
const baseUrl = new URL("127.0.01" + ':' + "8000");
const postsUrl = new URL('/api/posts/get-five-post-popular', baseUrl);

// TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

As we see, you would get a helpful error that something is wrong with your url!